# Python: How to print a message within a "frame", using if,for and while control statements? Really confused

Tags: python, loops

The user inputs a message, the number of times he wants the message to be repeated,
 and the "thickness" of the frame. It prints out the message within a frame consisting of '*','|',and'-' symbols. My program:

```
x = input("Enter the message:\n")
y = eval(input("Enter the message repeat count:\n"))`enter code here`
z = eval(input("Enter the frame thickness:\n"))


for top in range (z):
    print("|"*(z-1)+"+"+"-"*(len(x)+2)+"+"+"|"*(z-1))
for repeat in range(y):
    print("|"*z,x,"|"*z)
for bottom in range(z):
    print("|"*(z-1)+"+"+"-"*(len(x)+2)+"+"+"|"*(z-1))
```

example output with repeat count 3, frame thickness 2 and message:"Hello World"

```
|+-------------+|
|+-------------+|
|| Hello World ||
|| Hello World ||
|| Hello World ||
|+-------------+|
|+-------------+|
```

But that is not the required frame. This is how it has to look:

```
+---------------+
|+-------------+|
|| Hello World ||
|| Hello World ||
|| Hello World ||
|+-------------+|
+---------------+
```

Am i correct in using 3 different loops? I am struggling to 'double' loop the top and bottom parts of frame so that in each frame level, there is one "+" in each corner, a "-" along the top and bottom parts of the frame and a "|" along the left and right side. I thought it would be a similar concept to printing out a pyramid at the bottom and an inverted pyramid on top, but that got me  no where. The program i did above was the one that LOOKED the closest to the desired result. As you can see, each 'frame' on the top and bottom is different. ;(

These are the actual instructions:

Write a program to draw a frame (made of the characters +-|) around a message that has been repeated on consecutive lines.  There is a space before and after the message, and no spaces between concentric boxes.

Please help. Python V3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the loop variable as a depth hint:

```
x = " %s "%x # Add the spaces
for depth in range(z):
    # depth will be 0 on the first iteration, then 1
    print("|"*depth+"+"+"-"*(len(x)+2*(z-depth-1))+"+"+"|"*depth)
for repeat in range(y):
    print("|"*z+x+"|"*z)
for depth in reversed(range(z)):
    # reverse the depth values to start from the inner frame
    print("|"*depth+"+"+"-"*(len(x)+2*(z-depth-1))+"+"+"|"*depth)
```

There's obviously more than one way to do it, here is an iterative example :

You could use a function which takes a message as input and outputs the same message with a 1 level frame, then apply it as many times as your thickness requires.

```
def _one_frame(text):                 # text is supposed to be a list of lines
    lt = len(text[0])
    horz = '+' + '-'*lt + '+'         # Make the horizontal line +-------+
    result = [horz]                   # Top of the frame
    for line in text:
        result.append( '|'+line+'|' ) # Add the borders for each line
    result.append(horz)               # Bottom of the frame
    return result

def frame(text, repeat, thickness):
    text = [" %s "%text]*repeat       # add spaces and repeat as a list
    for i in range(thickness):
        text = _one_frame(text)       # draw one frame per iteration
    return '\n'.join(text)            # join lines

print(frame('Hello World', 3, 2))
```

Comment: What exactly does " %s " do? In the first solution, it prints out "%s" as being the message. The second one works, but i don't really understand it, because we were not taught in detail about how to use "append" and "return". I really appreciate your effort. Thank you so much.

Comment: Oops. %s is used for string interpolation (i should probably have used str.format instead) '%s'%'hello' substitutes %s by hello, I just forgot the substitution operation, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to replace `z` with `top`. And then, there is more logic, think about it:

```
for top in range(z):
    print '|'*top + "+" + "-"*(x+2 + (z-1)*2 - top*2) + "+" + "|"*top
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, name your variables sensibly, it makes it much easier to understand and correct:

```
message = input("Enter the message:\n")
repeats = eval(input("Enter the message repeat count:\n"))
thickness = eval(input("Enter the frame thickness:\n"))
```

Then you need to make the top of your frame do this:

```
widthWithFrame = len(message) + thickness*2

for i in range(0, thickness) :
  print("|"*i + "+" + "-"*(widthWithFrame-(i+1)*2) + "+" + "|"*i)
```

the rest I think you can figure out from there. Note that your example output includes extra spacing around the 'Hello World' not included in your code so you might need to remove then '+1' from '-(i+1)*2' if you want to allow for this.

Comment: sensible names but mixed up

Answer (score 0):

An object-oriented solution using the `__str__` method for string representation.

```
class MultiMessage(object):
    """represents the repeated message"""
    def __init__(self, text, count):
        self.text = text
        #self.text = " %s " % text #optionally add some spaces
        self.count = count

    def message(self):
        """data representation is a simple list"""
        return [self.text] * self.count

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(self.message())

class Frame(object):
    """a message wrapped in any number of frames"""
    def __init__(self, msg, thickness):
        self.msg = msg
        self.thickness = thickness

    @staticmethod
    def wrap(message):
        """wrap an array of data with a single frame and return as new data"""
        rows = len(message)
        cols = len(message[0])
        top = ''.join(['+'] + ['-' * cols] + ['+'])
        return [top] + ["|%s|" % row for row in message] + [top]


    def __str__(self):
        """wrap message and output a string"""
        result = self.msg.message()
        for i in xrange(self.thickness):
            result = self.wrap(result)
        return "\n".join(result)
```

This can now easily be used as in your example.

```
message = raw_input("Enter the message:\n")
count = int(raw_input("Enter the message repeat count:\n"))
thickness = int(raw_input("Enter the frame thickness:\n"))

m = MultiMessage(message, count)
f = Frame(m, thickness)

print f
```